# Subgrouping using "by_var" in "mada" does not work in one outcome

Tags: r

I am conducting a diagnostic test accuracy meta-analysis, using the "mada" package in R. Everything went well except one specificity outcome. While I use the same code in every other outcome and works great, it refuses to subgroup providing me an error.

Here is the code I used:

```
specificity_logit_sl <- metaprop(book1$TN, book1$TN+ book1$FP, comb.fixed=FALSE, comb.random=TRUE, sm="PLOGIT", method.ci="cp", byvar=book1$NC_RNA, studlab=book1$AUTHOR)
```

I also attach the code for sensitivity which works as expected:

```
sensitivity_logit_sl <- metaprop(book1$TP, book1$TP+ book1$FN, comb.fixed=FALSE, comb.random=TRUE, sm="PLOGIT", method.ci="cp", byvar=book1$NC_RNA ,studlab=book1$AUTHOR)
```

and the error I get is:
`Error in runGLMM(list.prop, method.tau = method.tau, method.random.ci = method.random.ci,  :  Error in (function (ai, bi, ci, di, n1i, n2i, x1i, x2i, t1i, t2i, xi,  :  Cannot fit ML model (set 'verbose=TRUE' to obtain further details).`

Has anyone else encountered this and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the error message and setting `verbose = TRUE`? Maybe this can give you some idea why it cannot fit the model.

Comment: Tried that. It does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with "metaprop" in the "meta" package. Adding sm="Plogit" fixed it.

```
metaprop(
    event = event.e, 
    n= n.e, 
    data=abc, 
    studlab = Study, 
    sm="Plogit", 
    level = 0.95,
    comb.fixed=TRUE, 
    comb.random=TRUE, 
    hakn=F, 
    method.tau="DL"
)
```